# Java Multidimensional Array convert rows to columns

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Currently i have the below mentioned table, the table has student data, every student has three records which depending on how many subjects student sat their exams, so if it is more subjects, it would become more records. also the fields data are same except the subject_id and the marks he/she gained that subject.

what i need is, to make every student single row instead of 3 rows, the subject_id(s) will be lay on top of the table, which i show roughly on the below code, i titled EXPECTING_ARRAY.

I tried by using another two dimensional array, but i got stuck how to move subjects to columns while they are rows.

```
        ###################### Current Array ##########################

        +----+---------+------------+------------+-------------+----------+-------------------+-------+
        | ID | stud_id | subject_id | teacher_id | activity_id | grade_id | accademic_year_id | Mark  |
        +----+---------+------------+------------+-------------+----------+-------------------+-------+
        |  1 |       2 |          4 |          1 |           1 |        2 |                 7 | 90.00 |
        |  2 |       2 |         11 |          1 |           1 |        2 |                 7 | 43.00 |
        |  3 |       2 |         12 |          1 |           1 |        2 |                 7 | 35.00 |
        |  4 |       3 |          4 |          1 |           1 |        2 |                 7 | 40.00 |
        |  5 |       3 |         11 |          1 |           1 |        2 |                 7 | 67.00 |
        |  6 |       3 |         12 |          1 |           1 |        3 |                 7 | 88.00 |
        +----+---------+------------+------------+-------------+----------+-------------------+-------+
```

..

```
    ###################### Expecting Array #####################################
    +------+----------+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+-----------+--------------------+
    | ID   |  stud_id |  subject_4 |  subject_11 |  subject_12 |  teacher_id |  activity_id |  grade_id |  accademic_year_id |
    +------+----------+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+-----------+--------------------+
    | ...  |        2 |         90 |          43 |          35 |           1 |            1 |         2 |                  7 |
    | ...  |        3 |         40 |          67 |          88 |           1 |            1 |         2 |                  7 |
    +------+----------+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+-----------+--------------------+
```

here is my java code

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    String[][] sheet = new String[7][8];


    //populating data [table heading];
    sheet[0][0] = "examId";
    sheet[0][1] = "studId";
    sheet[0][2] = "subject_id";
    sheet[0][3] = "teacher_id";
    sheet[0][4] = "activity_id";
    sheet[0][5] = "grade_id";
    sheet[0][6] = "accademic_year_id";
    sheet[0][7] = "Mark";

    //populating first student first row Row;
    sheet[1][0] = "1";
    sheet[1][1] = "2";
    sheet[1][2] = "4";
    sheet[1][3] = "1";
    sheet[1][4] = "1";
    sheet[1][5] = "2";
    sheet[1][6] = "7";
    sheet[1][7] = "90.00";

    //populating first student Second Row;
    sheet[2][0] = "2";
    sheet[2][1] = "2";
    sheet[2][2] = "11";
    sheet[2][3] = "1";
    sheet[2][4] = "1";
    sheet[2][5] = "2";
    sheet[2][6] = "7";
    sheet[2][7] = "43.00";

    //populating first student third Row;
    sheet[3][0] = "3";
    sheet[3][1] = "2";
    sheet[3][2] = "12";
    sheet[3][3] = "1";
    sheet[3][4] = "1";
    sheet[3][5] = "2";
    sheet[3][6] = "7";
    sheet[3][7] = "35.00";
    sheet[3][7] = "Mark";


//+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    //populating second student first row Row;
    sheet[4][0] = "4";
    sheet[4][1] = "3";
    sheet[4][2] = "4";
    sheet[4][3] = "1";
    sheet[4][4] = "1";
    sheet[4][5] = "2";
    sheet[4][6] = "7";
    sheet[4][7] = "90.00";

    //populating second student Second Row;
    sheet[5][0] = "5";
    sheet[5][1] = "3";
    sheet[5][2] = "11";
    sheet[5][3] = "1";
    sheet[5][4] = "1";
    sheet[5][5] = "2";
    sheet[5][6] = "7";
    sheet[5][7] = "43.00";

    //populating second student third Row;
    sheet[6][0] = "6";
    sheet[6][1] = "3";
    sheet[6][2] = "12";
    sheet[6][3] = "1";
    sheet[6][4] = "1";
    sheet[6][5] = "2";
    sheet[6][6] = "7";
    sheet[6][7] = "35.00";

//Testing Hard Coded Data   
/*for(int i = 0; i< sheet.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j< sheet[i].length; j++){
            System.out.print(sheet[i][j] +", ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }*/

    //I assume that the newTable will have at least one row suppose the   heading
    int new_rows = 1;

   //Finding how many rows, would be the new table
   //i skipped if rows has same stud_id, because every student will have    single row. so am count as distinct  
    for(int i = 1; i < sheet.length; i++)
        if(!sheet[i][1].equals(sheet[i-1][1]))
            new_rows++;

    int new_column = 0;
   //counting columns, i picked only first student how many rows has and then break the loop, so if it counts three same recording according to studId, it will be 3+ previous column - 2[which are marks and subject_id] 
    for(int i = 1; i<sheet.length-1; i++){
        new_column++;
        if(!sheet[i][1].equals(sheet[i+1][1]))
            break;

    }

    //checking how many rows and columns found [just for debuging]      
    System.out.println("Rows: "+new_rows+" And Columns: "+new_column);

    //creating newTable with new_records and new_column length
   // here i substract 2 [marks, and subject_id are gone]
    String[][] newTable = new String[new_rows][sheet[0].length + new_column -2];


    //here i need to populate data to newTable but how.....!!!!!!!
    for(int i = 1; i< newTable.length; i++){
        int j = 1;
        while(j < newTable[i].length){
            newTable[i][j] = sheet[i][j];
            if(!sheet[i][1].equals(sheet[i-1][1])){
                System.out.print(newTable[i][j]+" | ");
            }

            j++;
        }

        System.out.println();
    }


}
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: i want to convert my current multidimensional Array to the expected view, see the above mentioned "Expected..."

Comment: Yeah that i understood, but what is the EXACT problem with the code you posted, does the values go to the wrong place, does it crash, something else...

Comment: @litelite not showing what i intended to be

Comment: And what does it show right now

Comment: not showing anything sir;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129376/discussion-between-saedawke-and-litelite).